# how can I do reverse geolocation using mysql when all values are in the same table?

Tags: mysql, geolocation

this is my first question on stackoverflow.
I have a mysql table on my website that list earthquake origins, they all have latitudes and longitudes in the same table.

An example:

```
Date       | Time        | Latitude | Longitude | Depth | magnitude | Magnitude type
2017/04/03 | 03:08:37.20 |  -26.762 |    26.627 | 261.0 |       3.9 | WFEO
```

How can I add a reverse geolocation field in the same table where an approximate location name will be displayed?
I thought of downloading the Geonames database, and then putting that in a different table, and then querying the second table, but I don't know.
The mysql server is on a remote webserver.
Note: I am looking for a solution that will do each and every row in the table.
Thanks, I am new to mysql, so I don't have much knolledge in the field.
Any help would be appreciated.

What I've done so far.
I have a csv file which the earthquake parameters get recorded in, I've managed to put that in a mysql database to display as an html table. The code follows:

```php
<?php
$db =   new mysqli('localhost:3306','user','password','database');
if ($db->connect_errno) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $db->connect_error;
  exit();
}
?>

<table align="center" width="800" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse; border:1px solid #ddd;" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr bgcolor="#FFCC00">
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>Latitude</th>
            <th>Longitude</th>
            <th>Depth</th>
            <th>magnitude</th>
            <th>magnitude type</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
if(($handle     =   fopen("norcsv.txt", "r")) !== FALSE){
    $n          =   1;
    while(($row =   fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE){
        $db->query('INSERT INTO `events`(`date`, `time`, `latitude`, `longitude`, `depth`, `magnitude`, `magtype`) VALUES ("'.$row[1].'","'.$row[2].'","'.$row[3].'","'.$row[4].'","'.$row[5].'","'.$row[6].'")');
        if($n>1){
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row[0];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row[1];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row[2];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row[3];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row[4];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row[5];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row[6];?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php
            }
            $n++;
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<a href="index.html">View last seismic event location on a map.</a>
```

So as you can see, everything works, now I want to add a placename field in the current existing table to use the latitudes and longitudes to compute a geographical placename or maybe distance to placename.
Hope my question is clearer now.
Thanks everyone.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've updated the question to make it more clear, also added some code.